# List all instances with condition of a specific tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

My VPC has some instances, separated by tagging "Dept"(department). I then wrote a small iam policy to list all instances that share the same Tag (Dept:Sales). However, it resulted in "API error" of all resources in the EC2 dashboard.

I also tried using aws:RequestTag, aws:ResourceTag (global condition "aws" prefix) but the issue still persists.

I can list the instances if:
(1) I used other Actions (Ex: ec2:StartInstances or ec2:StopInstances).
(2) Change condition operator from "StringEquals" to "StringNotEquals" => Result: OK. From this, I understand the IAM request include "ResourceTag".

May you please explain how I can list the instances which share the specific tag?
Thanks.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:Describe*",
            "ec2:Get*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/Dept": "Sales"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some API Action & Resource that cannot be used with the ec2:ResourceTag/tag in the condition.

For `describe*`:

> Note that the Describe actions do not support resource-level
> permissions, so you must specify them in a separate statement without
> conditions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/control-access-with-tags.html

To learn whether an Amazon EC2 API action supports tagging, [see Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon EC2.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
When I replaced "StringEquals" by "StringNotEquals", I got the contrary result without any error that made me confused. I was not sure whether the condition resulted in a different value (not match the tag) OR it's unsupported.

By the way, is there any way to show the content of a request?

Once again, thanks.

Comment: See CloudTrail Event history for checking content of a request sent.